# When an element has display:none is it still clickable

Tags: html, css

I have found this really nice code for making a slider/switch...

[How to make a switch with CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp)

It utilises CSS only to make a checkbox appear as a switch.  Most of it I get however it doesnt have any javascript.  I was just wondering how the checkbox manages to change its :checked attribute when it is hidden??  Given that the css sets the input is set to display:none??

Comment: provide your code

Comment: No it's not clickable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A label that references an input has many of its events propagated to the host input element. For example a checkbox will still be toggled in the following two scenarios:

Label references child input by being a parent

```html
<label>
    <span>Click me too!</span>
    <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

Label references input by id:

```html
<label for="my-checkbox"><span>Or click me!</span><label>
<input id="my-checkbox" type="checkbox" />
```

---

In the case of your switch, the checkbox itself is hidden with `display: none` as you said. Instead of showing text like in the examples above, they inserted HTML to render a switch.

Answer (score 4):

```css
#check1{
  display: none;
}

label[for="check1"]{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#check1:checked + label[for="check1"]{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" />
<label for="check1"></label>
```

Use label tag.

And Use :checked Selector .

Comment: Thanks for the post but the question was in the title which was answered by @fond4218